# With top down architecture my business layer can't access my data access layer, what's wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, domain-driven-design

Using Asp.Net MVC I wanted a top down approach. I started using a top down approach but now it seems like it's an onion approach because my repository interfaces in the data access layer need to reference my model layer so it understands the objects it's returning. So now I'm referencing up and not down.

Now I have a method (LoadAllAppointmentsInDateRange) inside a model (DiaryEvent) in the business layer that needs to call the repository in the data access layer  below, but it can't because there would be circular references. How did I screw this architecture up and how can I fix it? Should I create another layer (service layer) that takes care of this and puts the method (LoadAllAppointmentsInDateRange) inside it or should I move my interfaces?

Here is what I have and what I want to do on a simplified level.

Controller (top layer) -

```
public JsonResult GetDiaryEvents(double start, double end)
    {
        var apptListForDate = DiaryEvent.LoadAllAppointmentsInDateRange(start, end);
        //do some other stuff
        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Business layer (middle layer) -

```
public class DiaryEvent
{

    public int ID;
    //other memebers here


    public static List<DiaryEvent> LoadAllAppointmentsInDateRange(double start, double end)
    {
        // logic here

        // want to access the repo here, but can't because data access layer is referencing this layer (business layer)
        IYogaSpaceEventRepository eventRepository = new YogaSpaceEventRepository();
        IQueryable<YogaSpaceEvents> events = eventRepository.FindEvents(startTime, endTime);


        //do some processing of the returned data
        return result;
    }
}
```

Access layer (bottom layer) - it references the business layer.

```
public class YogaSpaceEventRepository : IYogaSpaceEventRepository
{
    YogaContext context = new YogaContext();

    public IQueryable<YogaSpaceEvent> FindEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var rslt = context.YogaSpaceEvents.Where(s => s.DateTimeScheduled >= start 
            && DbFunctions.AddMinutes(s.DateTimeScheduled, s.AppointmentLength) <= end);

        return rslt;
    }  

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}

public interface IYogaSpaceEventRepository : IDisposable
{
    // here my repo (data access layer) is referencing my business layer to return YogaSpaceEvent
    IQueryable<YogaSpaceEvent> FindEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end); 
}
```

Comment: Why does your access layer need to reference the business layer? I don't see any dependencies in your code sample. Usually the business layer would reference the access layer. i.e. it needs to call the access layer to get the data in order to do its thing.

Comment: My access layer returns IQueryable<YogaSpaceEvent> in the interface, so it needs a reference to the business layer where YogaSpaceEvent resides. Maybe there's a better approach, please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should structure your project:

In you Business Logic Layer store your business entities and repository interfaces as follows:

```
public class YogaSpaceEvent
{
    // Function and Data Members
}

public interface IYogaSpaceEventRepository
{
    IQueryable<YogaSpaceEvent> FindEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end);
}

public class DiaryEvent
{
    private IYogaSpaceEventRepository _repository;

    public DiaryEvent(IYogaSpaceEventRepository repository)
    {
        this._respository = repository;
    }

    public static List<DiaryEvent> LoadAllAppointmentsInDateRange(double start, double end)
    {
        // Call appropriate method on _repository
    }
}
```

In your Data Access Layer (DAL), Add a reference to your BLL and implement the `YogaSpaceEventRepository` repository:

```
public class YogaSpaceEventRepository : IYogaSpaceEventRepository
{
    public IQueryable<YogaSpaceEvent> FindEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        // Retrieve Data from Database
    }
}
```

In your presentation Layer (MVC Controller) you first have to add a reference to your BLL and DAL, and then create an DiaryEvent object *injecting* an instance of the `YogaSpaceEventRepository` repository, like so:

```
public class PresentationLayer
{
    public void Test(double start, double end)
    {
        DiaryEvent diaryEvent = new DiaryEvent(new YogaSpaceEventRepository());
        var apptListForDate = DiaryEvent.LoadAllAppointmentsInDateRange(start, end);
    }

}
```

Comment: what advantage does the interfaces in the business layer achieve? is there a name or methodology to this structure that I can look up or that you can provide me pointers too? what advantages does this provide over creating a service layer and separating the core business entities from business logic?

Comment: I'm just following the principles of **Domain-Driven Design**. I would only create a separate Service Layer if the Domain Logic were too complex. Remember that adding a service layer adds another level of indirection that is not worth maintaining If it's just a CRUD-like service. You usually have as many Repository Interfaces as Aggregate Roots so it makes sense to store them next to your Entities in your BLL. Besides it makes testing easier (i.e: You could inject a fake repository). Hope it helps...

Comment: I'm not an expert at DDD, but have read a little. But following the rule of interfaces ("contract") that says what you have in an interface won't get changed, you essentially void the purpose of an interface by seperating them here between two assemblies (BLL, DAL), right?

Comment: No, not at all. To me the purpose of an interface in an n-tier application architecture is to achieve decoupling between layers and make code easier to test.

Comment: Maybe you can further answer my question here - I'm only using one DAL and it's to Sql Server via Entity Framework. So I have different repos in this DAL and the repos have interfaces, by having the interfaces here in the DAL, aren't I saying the the user of the DAL, here are my interfaces to use? access to the DAL is through the interface, right? If I remove that out of the DAL and into some other assembly then any contract I try to make with someone using my DAL doesn't exist. So doesn't that defeat the purpose of the interface?

Comment: That might be true. So you want to have your repo interfaces and implementations in the DAL assembly. I understand that it seems right to put all the repo interfaces in the DAL so that it can be consumed by the end-user. But it only makes sense when implementing a Service Layer. A DAL is usually specific to a Domain Model and so it makes sense to store the repo interfaces in the BLL. I did some research and found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13846209/3052062) that explains where to define the interfaces for a repository

Comment: You say "it only makes sense if implementing a service layer". What do you mean by that, can you elaborate please? Do you mean, if I have a service layer then my interfaces would resign there as well as the logic?

Comment: I think you're trying to encapsulate the DAL as if it were a service layer that exposes its service interfaces to a client. Let's say you put the repo interfaces and implementations in the DAL, then you would have to orchestrate the interaction between your DAL and Domain Model in a separate layer/assembly (i.e: Presentation or Service Layer). But what if you wanted to implement a new DAL for a different Data Source. You would have to maintain two identical copies of repository interfaces. It makes more sense to store them in your domain layer next to the appropriate domain object.

Answer (score 0):

If what you call the Business layer is equivalent to the Domain Layer in DDD, it shouldn't know about data access.

Delegate data access to an Application layer that knows the current application execution state, and keep your core domain devoid of persistence details. This way it is nicely decoupled -- you can put whatever persistence you wish and any number of applicative systems around it without changing the core business rules.

Comment: Sure, The Domain Layer shouldn't know about the implementation details of the DAL, but it should know about what data to expect. I think the Domain Layer shouldn't depend upon concrete DAL implementations (classes) but rather upon abstractions (Interfaces). This way you design your application to support multiple data sources.

Comment: No, the Domain typically doesn't know about a data source. Please read up on DDD and you'll realize there's an extra Application layer for doing this in that approach. And I'm only mentioning this because you put a DDD tag on your question, you are otherwise of course absolutely free to have your own concept of a "business layer" ;)

Comment: I never said the Domain should know about a data source. From what I've read an Application Layer (aka Service Layer) is used to orchestrate the interaction between your Domain Logic, Infrastructure and Data Access Layer. But it's not mandatory to have one. The question is If you had a simple 3-tier Application (Data Layer, Domain Layer, Presentation Layer) and were using the repository pattern where would you normally put your repository contracts/interfaces?

Comment: Repo interfaces *declared* in the Domain. But I'd *use* them in Controllers for lack of an Application layer. I wouldn't call them from the Domain layer (as seems to be the case in your code sample).

Comment: I totally agree. For simple applications that do not require a Service/Application Layer it makes more sense to use them in the MVC Controller. I just wanted to make my sample code resemble the code provided in the question :)

Comment: I'm sorry @chomba, I mistook you for the OP all the way. Monday, tired and all that... ;) Please don't take what I wrote for yourself. My bad.